# TX failed - Bad instruction - Funds not back

Tags: chainlink, failed-transaction

I sent some $link amount but TX failed due to Bad instruction error.

Tx is https://etherscan.io/tx/0xa45e443c8cf310dbe69ab725358ac2da20afde33442a55ed7df985fe6645057d

Have read that failed transactions like this should revert, and funds return to sender. But still not see in my Jaxx wallet. Do I have to wait more or should I already be having it back?

Thx!!

Answer (score 0):

When a transaction is reverted (e.g. due to a bad instruction or it runs out of gas), any ETH sent in that transaction is returned, except for the gas. You can calculate this with `Gas Price * Gas Limit`. You did not send any ETH in this transaction, but the transaction used 400,000 units of gas, with a gas price of 46 Gwei, resulting in 0.0184 ETH that is not returned to you.

You can read more about gas and how it works here: https://support.mycrypto.com/general-knowledge/ethereum-blockchain/what-is-gas

Comment: Thx for the answer, really good to know this procedure. The thing is, my Link are still not visible in my sender wallet. Should I expect this kind of delay? It's 12h from now. 

Thx!

Comment: Your tokens are still on your address. You can see your balance here: https://etherscan.io/token/0x514910771af9ca656af840dff83e8264ecf986ca?a=0x55dd3b3cd79b9d723f0e5691dd7866d3bb533f20

Comment: Oh yeah, thats true... then looks like jaxx wallet issue. Thx Morten!!!! Really appreciate it